# Stored few arrays in one array

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to store all this data into one array `cust_data` and after that, add new records with a while loop. But I'm using different types of data and don't have any idea on how to make this. Could somebody explain or give link to website with explanation how to make this.

```
int add_new_customer() {
    char name[50];
    char last_name[50];
    int phone_number;
    char address[50];
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", name);
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s", last_name);
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%d", phone_number);
    printf("Enter address: ");
    scanf("%s", address);
    char cust_data[100][256];
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check the function `sprintf()`which allows you to save a different type of variable in a string. (e.g: `sprintf(string,"%d",integer);`).

Comment: You can use a `struct` to store multiple arrays, or 2D arrays which are complicated to use in C.

Comment: rethink `scanf("%s", phone_number)`, where `phone_number` is of type `int[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd define a `struct customer_struct` that represents a customer, and an array of type `customer_struct[]` that represents a list of customers as follows.

```
typedef struct customer_struct {
    char name[50];
    char last_name[50];
    char phone_number[15];
    char address[50];
} Customer;

void add_new_customer(Customer *c) {
    printf("Enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", c->name);
    printf("Enter last name: ");
    scanf("%s", c->last_name);
    printf("Enter number: ");
    scanf("%s", c->phone_number);
    printf("Enter address: ");
    scanf("%s", c->address);
}

int main(){

    Customer customers[3];
    for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
        add_new_customer(&customers[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps :-)